# Jmeter-Saturation point

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can i know the critical point where the systems breaks.
To analyze the result is the toughest part in Jmeter.I failed to judge it because everytime the result  or listeners show different result
Can anyone suggest me what efforts should  i put so that i can easily say "that this website is crashing with 500 users or giving no response after certain point."
I also have a problem in configuring the threads that what combination should i entered in thread group.
 Because i have to report it further or needs to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting is JMeter's Achilles' heel. You can use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project which provides

1. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup) - which simplifies load scenario definition
2. [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) - which displays amount of active threads as your test goes
3. [Server Hits Per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond) - which provides information how many requests per second your threads provided

You can also consider using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool which simplifies the process of configuring and executing of JMeter tests and has rich reporting capabilities.